# cut a string in a specific field

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, cut

```
cat test.txt
/one/two/thre.erf;/four/five;4;4
/six/seven/eight.erf;/nine/ten/AABD_CASH_EDBC_FLOW;4;4
```

Desired output:

```
four
nine/ten
```

Did this : getting the output in one line - Issue.

```
cat test.txt| cut -d ';' -f2 | awk -F'/' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) printf("%s/", $i)}'
/four//nine/ten/
```

Any better way ?

Comment: I don't understand your desired output.  What are your general criteria that would produce that output?

Comment: @Lorkenpeist if you read OP's codes, (cat|cut|awk) you will know the criteria

Comment: where does `nine/ten` come from?

Comment: Please double check your update, you left in some of the desired output even though you removed the corresponding input

Comment: Sorry ...removed necessary info when editing. Update again !!

Comment: @iaav ur.... didn't notice that you change your question, I updated my answer for the new question.

Comment: And I edited the title of question a little, since I feel the original one is so hard to understand: **`cut to get last string and everything but last string`** feel free to roll back if the edit is bad/worse.

Answer (score 3):

You can get your desired output in one shot:

```
awk -F';' '{d=$2;f=$2
        sub(/\/[^/]*$/,"",d)
        sub(/.*\//,"",f)
        a[NR]=d;b[NR]=f}

        END{for(;++i<=NR;)print a[i]
            print ""
            for(;++j<=NR;)print b[j]}' file
```

will output:

```
/four
/nine/ten

five
AABD_CASH_EDBC_FLOW
```

**EDIT**

didn't notice that OP has change the question. The change made my above answer make no sense, but it made the question a lot easier. It could be done

with **awk**:

```
kent$  awk -F';/' 'sub(/\/[^/]*$/,"",$2)&& $0=$2' file 
four
nine/ten
```

or only with **grep**:

```
kent$  grep -Po '^.*?;/\K.*(?=/[^/]*$)' file
four
nine/ten
```

Answer (score 2):

One option with [vim](/questions/tagged/vim).

Content of `script.vim`:

```
set backup
g/^/normal df;x$dF/x
normal ZZ
```

Run it like:

```
vim -S script.vim test.txt
```

That modifies the file in-place yielding:

```
four
nine/ten
```

And also creates a backup file appending `~` suffix, that could avoid a game over at first attempt.

Comment: as you said, this will change (`ZZ`) the original file in place. so that OP's 2nd step cannot be done any longer. you may consider to first yank the content into a register. after the 1st step, paste the register at the end of the file, continue to do the 2nd step.

Comment: Oops... I didn't notice that OP changed the question..... the 2nd step disappeared.....!!!

Comment: @Kent: Sorry. I don't understand you. What do you mean with OP's 2nd step? The `cut` command? I understand that for each line he wants to extract from first colon until last forward slash? Why should I save content in registers? Did I missundersand anything? **EDIT**: *Ok. All clear. It seems that the OP has done a big change between edits.*

Answer (score 1):

### GNU sed

```
sed 's:^.*;/\(\w*/\w*\).*:\1:;1~2s:/.*::' file
```

..output is:

```
four
nine/ten
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|[^;]*;/([^;/]*(/[^;/]*)*)/.*|\1|' file
```

This presupposes that there are at least 2 `/`'s in the second field.

Answer (score 0):

```
 grep -Po '(?<=;)/[^;]*(?=/)' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while IFS=';' read -ra fields; do 
    d=$(dirname "${fields[1]}")
    echo "${d#/}"
done < test.txt
```